# I am using publish-subscribe model to get the data from one lwc component to another lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh, publish-subscribe

in my component B after saving the data to the database I am creating a publish call as shown:

```
handleSubmit(){
        var dataList = {};
        dataList.Id = this.data[0].Id;
        dataList.Name = this.name;
        dataList.DYNMPR__Active__c = this.active;
        dataList.DYNMPR__SourceObject__c = this.sourceObj;
        dataList.DYNMPR__TargetObject__c = this.targetObj;
        dataList.DYNMPR__Description__c = this.description;;
        this.newData = dataList;
        this.newData = dataList;
        console.log("this.EditData:: " + JSON.stringify(this.newData));
        updateData({mapObjData : this.newData});
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Record Update',
            message: 'The Record is Updated ',
            variant: 'success',
            mode: 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        const payload = {
            source: "Lightnign Web Component",
            messageBody: this.newData
        }; 
        publish(this.context, lmsDemoMC, payload);
        console.log('payload::' + JSON.stringify(payload));
        this.closeModal();
      //  return refreshApex(this.newData);

    }
```

In my component A I am calling the subscribe to get the data as shown:

```
getMapData(){
        var message;
        var name;
        fetchdata()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('result:::' + result);
                this.data = result;
                this.error = null;
                console.log('Data Connected callback' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
                this.recordid = String(this.data[0].Id);
                this.name = this.data[0].Name;
                this.sourceObj = this.data[0].DYNMPR__SourceObject__c;
                this.targetObj = this.data[0].DYNMPR__TargetObject__c;
                this.description = this.data[0].DYNMPR__Description__c;
                this.active = this.data[0].DYNMPR__Active__c;

                const parentPage = this;
                const name = this;
                this.channel = subscribe(this.context, lmsDemoMC, function (event){
                    console.log('I am here::' + event);
                    if (event != null) {
                        message = event.messageBody;
                        this.data = message;
                        const source = event.source;
                        //parentPage.receivedMessage = 'Message: ' + message + '. Sent From: ' + source;
                    }
                }, {scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE});


            })
            .catch(error =>{
                this.error = error;
                this.errorMsg = error;
                this.isEmpty = true;
            });  
    }
```

I am getting the message in, `message = event.messageBody;` and I want to save this message to `this.data` (declared as @track data) so that the latest data is shown on the UI. But its not working.

message that I have received from subscription :

```
  message::{"Id":"a013i000007L9qUAAS","Name":"Discharge Case Follow Up Mapping1","DYNMPR__Active__c":true,"DYNMPR__SourceObject__c":"Case","DYNMPR__TargetObject__c":"Case"}
```

when I print this.data nothing comes up on the console.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's console? Are any errors presented directly on the page? Have you tried debugging using the browser's javascript debugger? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/305905/edit) the question to add details about what you see and what you have tried to do to investigate the problem.

Comment: @PhilW I have added the result from the console. I get the message but it is not reaching the line this.data=message.

Comment: did you try parentPage.data=message since you have taken parentPage = this;

Comment: @User6670 Yes I did try that and I am getting the message on it as well, but not on this.data since I am using this.data to update the values on the UI.

Comment: so inside the function you can assign value to data using "parentPage.data" but it will be referencing the same "data" variable that you have tracked.

Comment: @User6670 Thank you so much it worked. I was trying parentPage.receivedMsg earlier, but when I tried parentPage.data I got the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Use "parentPage" to get access to data variable since we have assigned  "this" to "parentPage"

```
 if (event != null) {
      message = event.messageBody;
      const source = event.source;
      parentPage.data=message;

 }
```